# Post to Friends Wall in Windows 8 Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-8, friend, facebook-wall

The graphi api profile_id/feed to post to a friend's wall is being deprecated.
The blog https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/ directs that the feed/dialog should be used.

How can the feed/dialog be utilized in a Windows 8 application?  If it cannot how can a post to a friend's wall be done in a Windows 8 application?

Answer (score 0):

You could open a webview with the Feed dialog inside it, but otherwise there is no way to post to a user's friend's wall after the migration takes effect

Comment: Could I get the results from the feed dialog in this approach?

Comment: Yes, the feed dialog returns a post ID as its response